# Could not able resolve javax.inject: javax.inject:1.0 - Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am getting below error while running Gradle build in Unix terminal.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':imcalmsvc-service:compileClasspath'.
>   Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>          - https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1.0/javax.inject-1.0.pom
>          - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1.0/javax.inject-1.0.pom

However, there is no error while doing Eclipse-> Gradle refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the dependency wasn't found in either JCenter or Maven Central. When you are usure about the exact name of dependency or which repositories it is uploaded to, I recommend a search engine like [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/). It aggregates metadata from a lot of different Maven repositories and even shows you how to use them in Gradle.

In your case, you can find the `javax.inject` library [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1). Notice that the only published version is simply `1` and not `1.0`. Change this and it should work.